# Error when running npm run serve on brandnew Vue-CLI generated project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-cli-4

I've been trying to run `npm run serve` on a new vue Project generated with the Vue CLI.
I just create the project with `vue create app` then change directories to the project itself `cd app` and run `npm run serve` something I've doneeith other projects before, but since yesterday I've been getting this error:
I get this error:

```
INFO  Starting development server...
ERROR  Error: No valid exports main found for 'D:\Documents\app\node_modules\colorette'
Error: No valid exports main found for 'D:\Documents\app\node_modules\colorette'
at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:618:9)
at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:499:14)
at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:12)
at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:22)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:948:27)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:854:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(D:\Documents\app\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:5:17)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1128:30)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\acamp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-07T01_02_53_207Z-debug.log
```

I've already tried deleting my `node_modules` and then running `npm i` but it didn't solve it. Also tried updating vue CLI to the latest version, `npm i @vue/cli` but it didn't help either.

It happens with all the new projects I create
Please help!

Comment: If you delete `node_modules`, you should also delete `package-lock.json`. Also, `@vue/cli` should be installed globally, ie `npm i -g @vue/cli`

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5651

Comment: Upgrade your Node version to at least 13.7.0

Comment: Hi, thanks, I updated Node and it ran without problems

Answer (score -1):

Please update yours node-js to v14.x.x